# Given two trapezoids of equal area, show that the length of FB is (a^2 + b^2) / 2

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, quadrilateral

[image]

In the accompanying figure, i am told that the area of trapezoid BCGF equals the area of trapezoid FGED. With BC = a, and DE = b, i am to prove that the length of FG is sqrt((a^2 + b^2) / 2). Here is the suggested solution provided by my book:

> The areas of the three triangles are similar and therefore proportional with a^2, FG^2, and b^2. Since the area of triangle FGA is the mean of the areas of triangles DEA and BCA, we must have FG^2 = (a^2 + b^2) / 2.

Please help me in understanding why the areas of the triangles are proportional with a^2, FG^2, and b^2, and why FGA is the mean of the two other triangles. Thank you.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904527/find-length-of-trapezium-area-bisector/2904563

Comment: This is useful, could you also provide a little explanation for why the height of the upper triangle is h in you answer? But i can't find the relation between your answer and the approach used in my textbook, using the proportionality of the square of the bases and the area, Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $DE$ is parallel to $FG$ is parallel to $BC$

Then triangle $ABC, ADE, AFG$ are similar triangles.

The area of each then is proportional to the square of the base.

We can say that the area of triangle $ABC = \alpha BC^2$ and the area of triangle $AFG = \alpha FG^2$

Where $\alpha$ is some constant that depends on the shape of the triangle.  We don't know it, but we don't need to know it.

Area of Trapezoid $BCGF = $ area triangles $ABC - AFG = \alpha (BC^2 - FG^2)$

Area of Trapezoid $FGED = $ area triangles $AFG-ADE = \alpha (FG^2 - DE^2)$

$BC^2 - FG^2 = FG^2 - DE^2\\
2FG^2 = BC^2 + DE^2$

Comment: thank you, but my question was _why_ the area of the triangles are proportional to the square of its bases. I must have formulated myself badly.

Comment: It is the property of similar shapes.  All lengths are proportional.  If we increase the base by the same proportion as we increase the height, we can say that the area increases by the square of that proportion.  If we had a 3D solid, we could say that volumes increase by the cube of that proportion.